# What is an honest basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, terminology, vector-spaces

In a comment to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/96599/19341) question, the commentator stated that

"the monomials form an *honest* basis for your vector space".

To be honest, I never heard of that. Is this something elementary?

Comment: I mean ‘honest’ in the usual sense of the English word. There are other kinds of bases for special vector spaces: orthogonal bases, Schauder bases...

Comment: Thank you for your honesty.

Comment: Enough puns, honestly!

Comment: One standard term for an "honest basis", as opposed to a Schauder basis, is "Hamel basis".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not a term of art, but rather an attempt at emphasis. The monomials form a basis for the vector space in the usual sense (every vector is a linear combination of elements of the basis in a unique way), as opposed to, for instance, a Hilbert basis (whose linear span is not necessarily equal to the entire space).

(Reminds me of something that happened when I was taking Measure Theory in my final undergraduate year; the professor had his own very good notes, with a set of exercises. One of the problems asked us to prove that a function that satisfied a certain property "is automatically continuous"; we couldn't figure out what the definition of "automatically continuous" was, and asked the professor the next lecture. Of course, he meant that such a function would necessarily be continuous...)